# How to count time in Unity Pro?

Tags: automation

I am quite new in **Unity Pro** and I want to check if a variable is true during 2 seconds. I have tried with counter, but I got a syntax error. That was my line:
`CTU_0(CU := I_input, R := false, PV := 0, Q => O_output, CV => T#2s);`
Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, we will use the `Start` function inside of a [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) to get the current time in seconds. Then, in the `Update` function of that same behaviour, we can do any check within a given amount of seconds.

Below I demonstrate a component that runs arbitrary code for a given amount of seconds after a function is invoked...this will let you check if "a variable is true during 2 seconds".

```
// in TimerBehaviour.cs
using UnityEngine;
public class TimerBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    // set by Time.time whenever 'resetTime' is invoked
    public float startTime = 0f;

    // amount of seconds we will run some code for after 'resetTime' is invoked
    public float maxTime = 2.0f;

    // invoked to reset the clock and do something within 'maxTime'
    public void resetTime() {
        startTime = Time.time;
    }
    

    // invoked once upon initialization
    void Start() {
        resetTime(); // get the time upon startup
    }

    // invoked each frame
    void Update() {
        // first check if startTime is not equal to its initial value
        if (startTime != -1) {
            // now check if the current time minus start time is less than within time
                if (Time.time - startTime <= maxTime) {
                    // case: we are still within 'maxTime' seconds!
                    // check if a variable is true
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This provides the basic way to assess time, but to make sure the OP fully understands your guidance, can you edit your answer to provide a fuller example; e.g., by showing how to establish a loop that tracks the difference in seconds? That will make your answer more useful, and intuitive for future readers with a similar problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That would be awesome because I staill have no idea how to use it